# advanced validation using jquery validation and data annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm answering what is the best/cleanest way to make advanced validation in my case.

I have a model that I return to the View. I already use data annotation:

```
[Required]
public int dropdownList

[Required]
public int[] multiDropDownList
```

I already use jquery.valiation too for front.

I have to require multiDropDownList only if the value of dropdownList s different to 3 (values = 1, 2 or 3)

What could be the best way to do this? worst scenario should be to make custom check in controller and with JS in the front-end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have a number of useful validation attributes which may suit, for example `[RequiredIfNot]`

Comment: [RequiredIfNot("dropdownList", 3, ErrorMessage = "Error")] nice! thanks you can reply I'll validate this! I don't have to change the front-end js libraries or do I have to include another library?

Comment: Just need to install the nuget package and then include the `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` file in your view

Comment: perfect, what else? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was relying on built-in ASP.NET model validation before, but came up to decision that it's not flexible enough. In real world you have more complex logic. In your case you can implement IValidatable interface if you happy with server-side validation only.

But when you need validations on client side too, you can use [this approach](http://timgthomas.com/2013/09/simplify-client-side-validation-by-adding-a-server/).